# Positively oriened boundary of Q^3

Tags: real-analysis

First, an example in Baby Rudin Chapter 10 says that the positive oriented boundary of Q$^3$ is [e$_1$,e$_2$,e$_3$]-[0,e$_2$,e$_3$]+[0,e$_1$,e$_3$]-[0,e$_1$,e$_2$].   Any further explanation? How can we tell it is a positively oriented boundary?

Second, let J$^2$=F$_1$+F$_2$, where F$_1$=[0,e$_1$,e$_1$+e$_2$], F$_2$=-[0,e$_2$,e$_2$+e$_1$], why we can say J$^2$ is the positively oriented unit square in R$^2$? By drawing a picture, I can see that range of J$^2$ covers the unit square, but why it is a positively oriented boundary?

Comment: sorry to say. which level of math are you?

Comment: junior math major